# Symfony route {id}/ + redirect to or show correct slug if missing

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

On StackOverflow, for a question you will see in the url something like this: 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/{question.id}/{question.slug}`

If you remove the slug or change it, you will be redirected to a URL which contains the right slug, all done because only the `question.id` needs a match. I am trying to achive the same thing in a Symfony project. I've gotten far enough that the slug that is being entered (or left out) does not have any effect on the route. The only thing I have not achieved is the user being sent (or show) the full correct slug.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/{slug}", name="entity_show", defaults={"slug" = null})
 */
public function showEntity(Request $request, $id, EntityRepository $entityRepository)
{
   //.....rest of code here
```

So in short, what I have archieved is that any slug can be entered or no slug at all, but a redirect to the slug belonging to the `{id}` is not yet shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially you can get the Question object by using the [ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter) and in case the slug is wrong redirect to the proper route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/{slug}", name="entity_show", defaults={"slug" = null})
 */
public function showEntity(Request $request, Question $question, $slug, EntityRepository $entityRepository)
{
       if ($question->getSlug() !== $slug) {
           return $this->redirectToRoute('entity_show', ['id' => $question->getId(), 'slug' => $question->getSlug()]);
       }
       .... 
       do whatever you need
```